# MassTransit how to set timetout on unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit to exchange messages between two microservices, and I have a consumer that publishes an event when it receives a command message.

While adding a unit test to cover this message exchange I've noticed that when no event is posted the test takes about 30s to finish, which I assume is a default timeout.  Here's the xUnit unit test that reproduces the problem.

```cs
using System;
using Xunit;
using MassTransit;
using MassTransit.Testing;
using System.Linq;
using SomeProject.MassTransitInterface;

namespace SomeProject.MassTransitInterface.Tests
{

    public class CommandTests
    {

        [Fact]
        public void Test1 ()
        {
            var harness = new InMemoryTestHarness();

            var consumer = harness.Consumer<SomeCommandConsumer>();

            harness.Start().Wait();
            var command = new SomeCommand();
            harness.InputQueueSendEndpoint.Send(command);

            Assert.True( harness.Sent.Select<SomeCommand>().Any() );

            harness.Stop().Wait();

        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know if it's possible to tweak the timeout so that the test can fail after a couple of seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `TestTimeout` property on the harness, which is used by all created test components.

```
/// <summary>
/// Timeout for the test, used for any delay timers
/// </summary>
public TimeSpan TestTimeout { get; set; }
```

You should set it early, like in your test constructor, so that any token or timers set use the value.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Testing/AsyncTestHarness.cs#L30

Answer (score 0):

For everyone coming from Google:

There is now a configuration method: [SetTestTimeouts](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/cfd5d9fcc46b36240fa52e9ab123ee10aca9bcd5/src/MassTransit/Configuration/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionTestingExtensions.cs#L130-L150)

It can be used when initializing the service collection, as described in the documentation [here](https://masstransit.io/documentation/concepts/testing#test-harness-concepts):

```cs
.AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
{
    …
    x.SetTestTimeouts(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

})
```